# $(\infty,2)$-categories as colimits of orientals

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category represented by a fibrant simplicial set in the Joyal model structure. It is well known that $\mathcal{C}$ can be expressed as the (homotopy) colimit over its category of simplices.

This is a very convenient feature since it allows us to describe $\mathcal{C}$ as a certain $\infty$-categorical colimit
$$F:\Delta_{/\mathcal{C}} \to \operatorname{Cat}\!_\infty.$$

Now let us consider the case where we are working with an $(\infty,2)$-category $\mathbb{C}$, represented by a fibrant scaled simplicial set. Being careful with the scaling we can also present $\mathbb{C}$ as the (homotopy) colimit over its category of simplices.

I wonder if the same holds after "fattening" the category $\Delta_{/C}$ using the 2-categorical orientals. To explain this recall that for every $n\geq 0$ we have 2-categories $\mathbb{O}^n$ described as follows:

- The objects of $\mathbb{O}^n$ are given by the elements $i \in [n]$.
- The mapping categories $\mathbb{O}^{n}(i,j)$ are given by the poset of subsets $S \subseteq[n]$ with $S \neq \emptyset$ such that $\min{(S)}=i$ and $\max{(S)}=j$ ordered by inclusion.

Let us abuse notation and denote by $\mathbb{O}^n$ the fibrant scaled simplicial set obtained after applying the homotopy coherent nerve to be aforementioned 2-category.

We can define a category $\mathbb{O}_{/\mathbb{C}}$ as follows:

- Objects are given  by morphisms $f:\mathbb{O}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ of scaleds simplicial sets for $n\geq0$ and addition to morphisms of scaled simplicial sets $g:\mathbb{O}^2_\sharp \to \mathbb{C}$ where $\mathbb{O}^2_\sharp$ is obtained from $\mathbb{O}^2$ after localising the unique non-invertible morphism in $\mathbb{O}^2(0,2)$.
- The morphisms in this category are maps of scaled simplicial sets $\mathbb{O}^n \to \mathbb{O}^m$ making the obvious triangles commute.

There is a clear choice of functor of $\infty$-categories $$\mathfrak{F}: \mathbb{O}_{/\mathbb{C}} \to \operatorname{Bicat}_\infty$$
$$(f:\mathbb{O}^n \to \mathbb{C}) \mapsto \mathbb{O}^n$$

My question is: Is it true that $\mathbb{C}$ is the $\infty$-categorical colimit of $\mathfrak{F}$?

Comment: I haven't digested your precise question, but by [Loubaton's comparison](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.08504), we may work complicially. Maehara [showed](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09736) that the simplices are equivalent to the orientals. I want to say it's pretty formal in the compicial model that the simplices are dense. It follows that the orientals are dense in $(\infty,\infty)$-categories, and by reflection the 2-reflections of the orientals ought to be dense in $(\infty,2)$-categories (though this last step may be sensitive to whether the 2-trunctation is done strictly or weakly...).

Comment: @Tim Campion:  In the complicial model the full subcategory of simplices $\Delta(n) $ and $\Delta(n)_t$ for naturals n is dense in stratified simplicial sets. By Loubatons and Maehara's result and some formal considerations this implies that the orientals O(n) (weakly equivalent to $\Delta(n)$) and the n-1- truncations of the orientals $O(n) $ (weakly equivalent to $\Delta(n)_t$) form a dense subcategory of all $(\infty, \infty)$-categories. Is it also true that the orientals are a dense subcategory of all $(\infty, \infty)$-categories?

Comment: This would follow if one would know that the full subcategory of the orientals is dense in the full subcategory of the orientals $O(n)$ and the n-1 truncations of $O(n).$